Efficient Method For Applying Variable Pattern Densities Based on Shade Values in Illustrator?
I am trying to take an vector image that has multiple different shapes with varying shade values and apply a pattern to each shape that would increase the pattern size/density (say of overlapping circles) to each shape based on the shade of each shape, with increasing density for darker shapes or vice versa. I have included two images to attempt to explain what i am after. The method i used on this example was to draw a circle, use the transform/replicate to generate a symmetrical grid of overlapping circles, then create a 1x1 pattern, set the name of pattern to one end of the shade spectrum (ie. 100%), then use scale to increase/decrease the size of the pattern for the rest of the shade spectrum, then individually select each shape that is 100%, apply pattern, and repeat for 80%, 60% etc. Just looking for a magic button that will do this in 1 click, possibly 0 clicks if thats not asking too much. ;)
(https://ibb.co/YXT0057)
(https://ibb.co/28sGF9Y)

You can shorten the procedure a little. Because you have only a few greyshades you can make to the swatches collection the corresponding patterns beforehand. Or you can use some of the standard fill patterns.
Select one of the areas, say one 20% black shape. Then select all of them by applying Select >Same > Fill color and apply the corresponding pattern. If you have for example 5 different shading patterns you must repeat this only 5 times, no matter your drawing may have hundreds of separate shapes. The next version uses Illustrator's standard circular dot patterns:

Their dots were scaled to a good size at the same time by selecting all (after applying the patterns) and applying Object > Transform > Scale > only patterns.
An opinion:
It's useless to have somehow complex patterns. Their details will be lost. If they have easy to see complex details one loses the big picture. I would use equally sized black dots. Such pattern can be got automatically.
I converted a screeshot (360px x 360px) of your example in GIMP to 2 color (Black and white) Floyd-Steinberg-dithered bitmap and traced it pixel perfectly (no smoothing, no speckle reduction, no optimization) in Inkscape. The result looks this:

Photoshop's image mode Bitmap > Diffuse dithering does the same.
After tracing it pixel perfectly it looks the same as when it was a dithered bitmap in GIMP. Zooming in and scaling up do not increase blurriness because it's a vector. Here's a zoomed in view in Inkscape:

A third party add-on may do the same job 100% in Illustrator,even maybe the expected 1-click version, but I do not have such piece of software. Check the catalog of Astute Graphics.
Late addition: Your example resembles some commercial drawings in image marketing websites so much that it's not at all clear who actually owns the rights. Let's hope it's you or the original is in public domain.
